# removing some files out of several folders

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a question about removing some files out of several folders.
To be more specific: There are 5 Folders which are only the same by a few characters. For example: o1_FolderF_xy and zz_FolderF_34. And in each folder with the characters "FolderF" I want to delete all the files which starts with "filename".
The last time I did it by hand. 
Will this work? Or do i need a script with a loop?

```
rm -rf /path/toFolder/*FolderF*/filename*
```

I'm sorry, I think for most it's a stupid question. But I'm new to all the stuff and I just do not want to go wrong with the delete

Comment: You can test with `echo ` instead of `rm -rf` to see what the wildcard matches.

Comment: thats a cool idea thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) instead:

`find /path -name 'filename*' -exec rm {} \;`

Basically it search's files with *filename* pattern on */path* directory and for each file it executes *rm*.

Or, if you want to just check into those specific directories:

`find /path -wholename '*folder*/filename*' -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: find also has the `-delete` action flag.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggested command will work just fine.